# The web service returns xml - ksoap2

Tags: android, xml, web-services, android-ksoap2

I am using ksoap2 to consume  a third party web service in my application. The webservice returns XML data. My search is told me that ksoap2 does not support xml.

Moreover when I am doing something like this in my client,

```
htse.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
```

it gives the following exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.SoapFault cannot be cast to org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
```

Again, my search has told me that this is because the data returned is probably in XML, or some type other than soapObject.

Please suggest me how to consume this web service in my client using ksoap2.

Note:- I have used an empty string as a soapAction, since in the WSDL it is an empty string.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ksoap does supports XML.

When you call envelope.bodyIn, it either returns SoapObject or SoapFault.
you should handle it using below code:

```
if(envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapObject)
    {
        return data;
    }
    else
        throw (SoapFault)envelope.bodyIn;
```

in your case you are getting soapfault object. This means either your request is not correct or server is returning error message for your request.
Check your request paramters, as most of the times request values in SOAP object(SoapSerializationEnvelope...) are not correctly set.
Also in my view, soapAction should not be empty. Try to test your WSDL using SOAP-Sonar etc. check for the values which are giving the successful response.

EDIT:
check for the request and response dump.

httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

Log.d("MyAPP", "----------------- " + httpTransport.requestDump
                + "\r\n\r\n" + httpTransport.responseDump);

Comment: I did test all the methods provided in the WSDL using SOAPUI. I got a perfect XML response.

Comment: you can check for the request and response dump and see if you are sending the data as expected. editing my response for the logs.

Comment: OK.. I am new to android.. and I don't about Logging or Logs, except that I see them everywhere, and I am going to need them a lot. So I'll get familiar with them in a day, and get back to it.

Comment: Can you tell me what you mean by request and response dump?

Comment: you can simply print it on console too. like : System.out.println("MyAPP", "----------------- " + httpTransport.requestDump + "\r\n\r\n" + httpTransport.responseDump); httpTransport is the AndroidHttpTransport object.

Comment: `12-01 05:52:28.947: W/EGL_emulation(1027): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-01 05:52:29.546: W/System.err(1027): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.SoapFault cannot be cast to org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
12-01 05:52:29.546: W/System.err(1027):  at com.example.testsearchpublications.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:42)
12-01 05:52:29.546: W/System.err(1027):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
` This is the LogCat now, after I added the statement to print reqiestDump and responseDump.